# ImageView is not being set with Image captured through Camera

Tags: javascript, android, camera, gallery

I have used a `CircleImageView` using the `'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'` library.

code:

```
 @Override
       public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){

           switch(item.getItemId()){
               case R.id.slot1:
                   Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                   if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                       // Create the File where the photo should go
                       File photoFile = null;
                       try {
                           photoFile = createImageFile();
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                       if (photoFile != null) {
                           cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                           startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                       }
                   }
                   return true;
               case R.id.slot2:
                   Intent i = new Intent();
                   i.setType("image/*");
                   i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                   return true;
               default:
                   return true;
           }
       }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "Widget_profile_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  // prefix
                    ".jpg",         // suffix
                    storageDir      // directory
            );

            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            photoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        }
```

and in the onActivityResult()  method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
            profile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            profile.setImageBitmap(photo);

        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            profile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i have created a menu option to select between **Gallery** and **Camera** where the Gallery seems to work perfectly, but Camera option doesn't set any image.

```
public void setImage(View view){

        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(1, R.id.slot1, 1, "Camera");
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(1,R.id.slot2,2,"Gallery");
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you declared this in your manifest?
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

Comment: yes i have, and i managed to get the code working! turns out, the image file path was not being saved.

Comment: Glad to know you solved it. I would suggest you to also answer your question and mark that answer accepted,  so that others know that your problem was solved. :)